# Enable Wireless on Ubuntu on a mac pro 1.1

Tags: mac

How Do i get my wireless working, I just installed Ubuntu on my 2006 Mac Pro 1.1

Comment: In order to get help more information is needed.  Do you get an error or does the wireless card not actually show up?
Please help provide us more information around this so we can help you out more

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a couple of weeks benchmarking some linux distros like:

- Mint with Cinnamon desktop environnment
- Ubuntu
- The new Debian 7.4
- Fedora
- CentOS
- EliveCD

And I have EliveCD installed because of the full support of the mac hardware (i.e. the WiFi chipset) and Elive works pretty fluently.